# Linking against a .lib causes many multiply defined symbols

Tags: c++, visual-c++, build, linker, googletest

I downloaded [Google Test](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/w/list) and built it under MSVC 2010. I then linked its target, gtest.lib (or, gtestd.lib under Debug Configuration) against my executable.

The outcome is a long list of multiply defined symbols. In short:

```
error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
error LNK2005: _vprintf already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
error LNK2005: _printf already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
```

and the list goes on and on. Most are VC runtime symbols but a few are gtest symbols. What error have I made? The [gtest primer](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/V1_5_Primer) states:

> To write a test program using Google Test, you need to compile Google Test into a library and link your test with it.

But doesn't really elaborate beyond that.